# MySql re-utilizando resultado de subquery

Tags: mysql

em mysql existe uma forma onde eu possa re-utilizar o resultado de uma subquery dentro da query principal?

```
select
(select resultado from tabela limit 1) as resultado_subquery,
(resultado_subquery * outra_coluna) as teste
from tabela
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer algo como o exemplo abaixo:

```
select
subquery.resultado,
(subquery.resultado * outra_coluna) as teste
from tabela
left join (select codigo, resultado from tabela limit 1) as subquery on (tabela.codigo = subquery.codigo)
```

Resumindo, você pode por a subquery no LEFT JOIN como uma tabela temporária, mas terá que relacionar com alguma chave do SQL principal, como exemplo a coluna *CODIGO* é a chave.